# Importing sqlite3.h to a Swift project via a Obj-C bridging header doesn't work

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, swift

I have created a file called `BridgingHeader.h` and it contains only one line:

```
#import <sqlite.h>
```

And of course the framework `libsqlite3.dylib` is imported either.

In my build settings I've also set the value of **Objective-C Bridging Header** to `<ProjectName>/Bridging-Header.h`

BUT…

When I add `import sqlite3` to my Swift class it says that it cannot find the module `sqlite3`.

Comment: SQLite has a C interface, not an Objective-C interface.

Comment: @rmaddy So I have to write a whole wrapper in `Obj-C`?

Comment: There is already is one (not that I've used it): FMDB.

Comment: You don't need to import in your swift class, it's implicitly done by adding it to your bridging header.  That said, I haven't had any luck calling any `sqlite3_open` variant yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For anyone who does want to use SQLite 3 directly, see this Gist:

https://gist.github.com/zgchurch/3bac5443f6b3f407fe65

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @trojanfoe I am using now a library which is an `Objective-C` wrapper for the `sqlite3` framework. ([FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb))

Got it to work by importing the `ObjC` header in my `BridgingHeader.h` file and using the class without importing anything in the `Swift` class.

<sub>Conclusion: Only Objective-C files can be imported into the bridging header…</sub>

Comment: Your conclusion is not correct - you can import sqlite3.h into your bridging header. See my answer below.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how you are importing the `ObjC` header in the `BridgingHeader` file? I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: @flippex17 add the line: `#import "yourheader.h"`